# Link synonyms to a common identifier

Tags: r, split

I have a R dataframe (gene information, ~20000 entries) that looks like this once simplified:

```
> head(alias_db)
   Synonyms               dbXref   
1  PA1m|A2m|AI893533|MAM  ENSMUSG00000030359
2  AA-NAT|Nat-2|Nat4|Snat ENSMUSG00000020804
```

A gene has different names (synonyms) separated by "|" and a dbXref field (database identifier). I would like to create a new data frame looking like this:

```
  Names dbXref
1 Pzp   ENSMUSG00000030359
2 A1m   ENSMUSG00000030359
...
4 MAM   ENSMUSG00000030359 
5 Aanat ENSMUSG00000020804
...
```

Basically, the synonyms are the keys and the dbXref field my values; I want to be able to search any name in synonyms and then use its dbXref to look up another larger dataframe.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of this:

```
alias_db$SplitSynonyms=strsplit(alias_db$Synonyms,"|",fixed=TRUE)
geneNames<-new.env()
for(i in seq(nrow(alias_db)))
  {
    lapply(alias_db$SplitSynonyms[[i]],function(x) geneNames[[ x ]] <- alias_db$Ensembl[i])
  }
```

I don't know if this is really efficient. sapply should be slower than a for loop, and then I use lapply on the lists created by strsplit. The environment is used as key value dictionnary. 
The worse part is that I don't obtain a dataframe as requested....

Comment: I’d have expected this to be trivial with tidyr, but looking over the documentation I cannot see a way to do this.

Comment: Just one last thing:: it is not really efficient I guess, but I can use this line to get a dataframe:

   geneSynonymLookupTable=as.data.frame(as.list(geneNames))

Comment: @KonradRudolph, the approach would be along the lines of `alias_db %>% mutate(Synonyms = strsplit(Synonyms, "|", TRUE)) %>% unnest(Synonyms)` but I'm biased in favor of `cSplit` :-)

Comment: Was the [tag:tidy-data] that you created applied then deleted without showing up in the edit log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package, like this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(alias_db, "Synonyms", "|", "long")
#    Synonyms             dbXref
# 1:     PA1m ENSMUSG00000030359
# 2:      A2m ENSMUSG00000030359
# 3: AI893533 ENSMUSG00000030359
# 4:      MAM ENSMUSG00000030359
# 5:   AA-NAT ENSMUSG00000020804
# 6:    Nat-2 ENSMUSG00000020804
# 7:     Nat4 ENSMUSG00000020804
# 8:     Snat ENSMUSG00000020804
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the package: it is indeed what I wanted (and as a one liner). It is not often (in my experience) that a field in a R dataframe has to hold several values (here maybe none, maybe 1-5 here), but this solves the issue in a neat way.